# Use of Break in SPSS Macro

Tags: macros, spss

I want to use BREAK statement in my Macro but cannot figure out the way to use them. Please refer to the below code for the same.

I have gone through some blogs over Google to see ho to use BREAK in the MACRO, but none could help me with MACRO.

`'!DO !k=!arg3 !TO !arg5
IF(!CONCAT('brand_',!i,'=',!j) AND ~missing(!CONCAT('DD_brand_',!k,'_',!i))) !CONCAT('DD_brand_',!j,'_a2')=!CONCAT('DD_brand_',!k,'_',!i).`

The issue is in K loop which is looped in 500 times, for searching a value. But out of 500, only 1 variable has data, and the rest 499 are empty. Currently it is looping in 500 times, no matter where it finds the Data.

I want to Break out of the loop as soon as the Data is encountered in the set of variables for particular j loop iteration.

Comment: Since SPSS macros do not evaluate the data itself but only create the syntax, you can not break a macro loop based on a value in the data. Maybe you can find the needed number of iterations in advance and get the number in as macro argument.

Comment: I am trying to figure that out, but the problem I am getting is data can lie in any of 500 variables, and that 500 set is running another 100 times,i.e., 100*500 iterations. I know macro creates the Syntax, can I create the SPSS synatx with break in the current macro shown above?

Comment: Loop command in regular syntax has a few methods for breaking given a specific condition. You might be able to base the loop on regular syntax loop instead of macro loop - and use macro to define the variable lists for the loop and the breaking condition. If you add a more detailed explanation + example to your post I could try to suggest something more specific.